# Windows Batch: echo problems

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was trying to write multiple lines with a batch file like this->

```
@echo off
(
echo 123()
echo abc
) > exampleFile
```

the problem is in the third line of the code:

```
echo 123()
```

I think its the closing **)**.

How to prevent this?
Is there any kind of c or c++ like escape characters for the echo command?
Thanks for help, true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) with a caret;

```
@echo off
(
echo 123(^)
echo abc
) > exampleFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "for_echo=123()"
(
echo !for_echo!
echo abc
) > exampleFile
endlocal
```